# How to check whether an android device has  gps support or not?

Tags: android, gps

i'm trying to write a method which checks the gps support of android device.
Although having gps support on emulator, it always returns false. But when i try it on my android devices it returns true. What can be reason of that?

```
public boolean isGpsAvailable() {
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way it doesn't work only on emulator. it works perfect on my android device.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899621/how-can-i-check-for-gps-support-in-app-to-add-a-feature-for-those-with-location

Comment: Pay attenction, your code will crash on device before FROYO. PackageManager.FEATURE_LOCATION_GPS is API LEVEL 8

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a LocationManager, you could use this method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getAllProviders%28%29

Then look through all of the strings returned, and see if one is a GPS provider.

Comment: I have tried your way before, and it works perfect. But i really wonder why this code snippet does not work?